# https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites?search=* is broken in beta

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites?search=* fails with error

{
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Syntax error: character '*' is not valid at position 0 in '*'.",
...
}
}

However on 1.0 ((https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*)) this works fine and returns all the sites associated

Our application relies on this API to fetch all the sharepoint sites associated with a company. Is the beta behavior a bug?

Comment: It fails only with "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites?search=*", but it works for me with "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites?search=test".

Comment: I am specifically talking for support for '*' to enumerate all the sites and subsites associated with a sharepoint instance. This works in v1.0 but not in beta

Comment: Yes, thats what i said above too. It works for rest, except "*". Sounds like its broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beta endpoints are currently in preview and are not yet generally available, it may be not suitable for the production environment.

If you want to fetch all the sharepoint sites, you may consider using following workaround:

There is a list in tenant-admin site that stores a cached copy of aggregated site collections data from all contentdb.

Get tenant -admin site:

[image]

Find the lists: DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_AGGREGATED_SITECO and DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_ALL_SITES_AGGREGA

[image]
[image: 29591-image.png]

These lists contain all site collection info.

[image: 29545-image.png]
[image: 29572-image.png]

One list includes personal site and another does not.